# When substituting $x=e^t$ how does $x(dy/dt)=dY/dt$ yield the ODE $Y''=Y'(Y+1)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

**Background(unimportant)**: This is from Arfken, Weber, Harris describing how unlike LDE, NDE's have solutions with singularities that move when the initial value is changed: Both $y'+\frac{y}{x-1}=0$ and $y'=y^2$ have the solution $y=1/(1-x)$ when y(0)=1, howevever for the initial condition y(0)=2 the LDE singularity is the same: $y=1+1/(1-x)$ while the NDE singularity moved $y=2/(1-2x)$ They also have special solutions not reachable by two independent solutions:

**Question**
How was the ODE equation underlined below derived? if $x=e^t$ I get
$$\frac{d}{dt}(dY/dt=x(dy/dx))$$
$$\frac{d^2Y}{dt^2}=x(dy/dx)+x^2(dy/dx)$$
$$Y''=Y'+e^t Y'$$

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With $x=e^t$ 
\begin{align}
\dfrac{dY}{dt}
&=\dfrac{d}{dt}y(x)\\
&=\dfrac{d}{dx}y(x)\dfrac{dx}{dt}\\
&=y'(x)x\\
\dfrac{d^2Y}{dt^2}&=\dfrac{d}{dt}(y'(x)x)\\
&=\dfrac{d}{dx}(y'(x)x)\dfrac{dx}{dt}\\
&=(y'+xy'')x\\
&=x(xy'')+xy'~~~~~~~\text{from main equation}\\
&=x(yy')+xy'\\
&=xy'(y+1)\\
&=Y'(Y+1)
\end{align}

Comment: That's it! I forgot to take the derivative of y' in the $y''x^2$ term

Comment: Yea! The main equation is The main goal. Good luck.